# how to open large .mat file that wasn't saved with -v7.3 flag?

Tags: matlab, file, save, load

I am trying to open a .mat file with one huge array in it.
When I use matfile function like below:

```
file=matfile('input_file');
```

Following errors show up:

> Warning: The file 'C:...\input_file.mat' was saved in a
>   format that does not support partial loading. Temporarily loading variable 'var_name' into memory. To use partial loading
>   efficiently, save MAT-files with the -v7.3 flag.
>
> Error using my_function (line 11)
>   Cannot read file C:...\input_file.mat.

How can I "resave" it properly? Or is there any other way to load data from the file?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To load a file, you can:

1. Double click on that file in the workspace directory.
2. Use the command:

   load('file.mat');

To save a file after processing data, you can use:

```
save('filename.mat',nameobj,'-v7.3');
```

or

```
save('filename.mat',nameobj);
```

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that simple loading doesn't work, because file is too large